# How to upload new spreadsheet with data to googledocs?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I try to use Google Spreadsheets API and Google Documents List API, butI can't understand how to add new generated form scratch spreadsheet.

I find how to add *empty* spreadsheet (C#):

```
DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();
entry.Title.Text = title;
entry.Categories.Add(DocumentEntry.SPREADSHEET_CATEGORY);
DocumentEntry newEntry = documentsService.Insert(DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri, entry);
```

But how to fill it by data? May be with [updating cells with a batch request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#updating_multiple_cells_with_a_batch_request). But WorksheetEntry is needed for it. There is no way to get WorksheetEntry from DocumentEntry (it's only possible by worksheet searching in SpreadSheetFeed::Entries)

Is there any normal way to upload new generated spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the spreadsheet with data but the whole spreadsheet will be overridden. I didn't find a way to update a portion of the spreadsheet without incurring significant performance penalty.

The code below assumes that documentService is DocumentsService and entry is DocumentEntry.

```
var factory = (GDataRequestFactory)documentService.RequestFactory;
factory.CustomHeaders.Add("If-Match: " + entry.Etag);

var mediaUri = new Uri(entry.MediaUri.ToString());

documentService.Update(mediaUri, "your-csv-string-here", "text/csv", entry.Title.Text);
```